# too many grid cell can't auto placement in right place

Tags: css, vue.js, layout, grid, css-grid

vue code here:

```
<template>
    <div class="live-room-list">
        <div class="test">
            <div
                class="item"
                v-for="(item, index) in list"
                :key="item.height"
                :style="{
                    'grid-row': `span ${Math.ceil(item.height)}`
                }"
            >{{index+1}}: {{item.height}}</div>
            
        </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            list: Array.from({ length: 10 }).map(_ => {
                return {
                    height: Math.random() * 300 + 10
                };
            })
        };
    }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scope>

.test {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 0 5px;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
    grid-auto-rows: 1px;
}

.item {
    border: 2px solid rgb(226, 199, 77);
}
</style>
```

When I set `length` a small value, everything is ok. But when `length` is big, cells will overlap like:

[image: pic]

Is there any explanation?

I could not find on Google a similar situation.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more precisely what you are trying to achieve? It's not really clear, at least for me.

Comment: I want to achieve masonry layout

Answer (score 0):

If you're only bothered by the overlapping (vertical) borders, why don't you simply set the row gap on your grid-gap as well?

```css
.test {
  grid-gap: 5px 5px;
}
```